# Why is my Bootstrap 5 hover class not working?

Tags: css, button, css-selectors, hover, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to change the bootstrap button into a hover but it's not working.

HTML:
`<button type="button" class=" btn btn-dark">Sign Up</button>`

CSS:
`.btn-dark:hover { color: blue }`

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example please?

Comment: This is not reproducible: https://codeply.com/p/HB3gkizGks ... please provide MRE.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included your custom CSS file *after* your bootstrap css include?
This makes a difference as it will read your custom tag last and apply that over the bootstrap style.

also you could overwrite the scss file.
https://www.bootstrapdash.com/bootstrap-css-styles/

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because of the css *specifity*:

Use `.btn.btn-dark:hover { color: blue }` (i.e. all classes for that element combined in the css selector) to overwrite the regular rule for that element.